# Global sections of a line bundle vanishing on a subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a (smooth) variety, and let $Y$ be a subvariety (or closed subscheme) of $X$. We  also have an ample line bundle $L$ on $X$, and suppose that $\dim H^0(L)=n$.
I want to focus on the cohomology group $H^0(I_Y \otimes L)$, where $I_Y$ is the ideal sheaf of $Y$ in $X$, and in particular on its dimension.

I know that $H^0(I_Y \otimes L)$ is the vector space of all global sections of $L$ which vanish on $Y$; so, if $\dim H^0(I_Y \otimes L)=n$, then all global sections of $L$ vanish on $Y$. This means that the subvariety $Y$ is contained in the base locus of $L$ (or maybe is it exactly the base locus?).

The question is: what happens if $\dim H^0(I_Y \otimes L)<n$ ? How can we describe $Y$ geometrically if, for example, the dimension is $n-1$ ? Does $Y$ have some restriction or constrains, like in the case of dimension $n$ ?

Thanks for the help.

Edit: correction in the assumptions (see first comment).

Comment: You have too many issues. $H^0(I_Y\otimes L)$ may not be finite dimensional if you do not assume, say, $X$ is projective. Even if it is, $H^0(I_Y\otimes L)=n$ does not mean ALL global sections of $L$ will vanish on $Y$,  since in general $H^0(L)$ will have larger dimension than $n$. For example, try $X=\mathbb{P}^1$, $Y=p$, a point and $L=O(1)$.

Comment: @Mohan, you are absolutely right, I've written it badly. I'll edit the question